# Is there is any function like No response in CAPL

Tags: capl

I am new Canoe and capl programming i want to request can message and if no response then my test case should pass there is any cmd available in vteststudio.
please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
testWaitForMessage
```

with the appropriate message and timeout.

The call will return -1 when the message was not received within the given time.

Then you can set the verdict using `testStepPass` or `testStepFail`.